# SQL to select between two rows

Tags: sql, between

I have a table like this:

```
  C         A         B
-------|----------|-----------|
  16         11111       030000
  16         11111       050000
  16         11111       080000
  16         22222       010000
  16         22222       020000
  16         22222       050000
  16         22222       060000
  16         22222       070000
```

I need to select all between 11111 050000 and 22222 050000 including.

What SQL is correct?

The last I have and it doesn't work :

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE A <= 22222 
  AND B < 050000 IN (SELECT id FROM table 
                     WHERE C = 16 AND B >= 050000 
                       AND A BETWEEN 11111 AND 22222
```

Comment: yep, that’s a syntax error (`B<050000 IN (`), and it’s far more complicated than it needs to be. Your sub query is close, but I get the feeling that these are probably date and time columns?  That changes what you can do, if that’s the case.

Comment: A is INT. B is VARCHAR.

Comment: Without context of what these fields represent, it’s difficult to know what assumptions can be made about the data. I guessed dates because it looks like you’re wanting a date range. But from what you’ve given you probably need to concat the fields together so that you can test a range. If that’s possible on your database. BTW, that would be s good tag to add, which database you’re using. good luck, I’m calling it a night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few engines, like SQLite, that will let you compare rows to rows directly:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (A, B) BETWEEN (11111, '050000') AND (22222, '050000')
```

But of course, this is not standard, and you might find yourself needing to do this in an engine that requires you to write standard SQL code. In that case, the question is, what does it imply for values to be between those two rows?

In this case, the table is sorted by A and then B. So for a row X to be between row P and row Q, then (writing R(C) to mean column C of row R) either P(A) < X(A) < Q(A) (because in that case the value of A is strictly between them, and since A is the primary sorting key, the row will always be there) or the value of A matches one of the endpoints and then the value of B is considered. This breaks down into two cases: P(A) = X(A) and P(B) <= X(B), and X(A) = Q(A) and X(B) <= Q(B).

There's also a special case: if P(A) = Q(A), then only B matters, but this has to be handled specially, because using the two conditions above separately will match excess rows.

So, let's write all of this into a parameterized query, using four query parameters `:a1`, `:b1`, `:a2`, `:b2` to show all cases:

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table
WHERE
  CASE WHEN :a1 = :a2 THEN
    B BETWEEN :b1 AND :b2
  ELSE
    (A > :a1 AND A < :a2) OR
    (A = :a1 AND B >= :b1) OR
    (A = :a2 AND B <= :b2)
  END
```

And that's the general solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Temp_Table WHERE CAST(B AS int)  BETWEEN  050000 AND 050000
```

This will help you.